# How to check return status of command invoked from command line in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, exit-code

```
reg import RegFile.reg
```

How to check return code of this command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit status of the last command should be stored in the ERRORLEVEL variable. Run this after running your `reg` command:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```